# How to add links to images created by a while loop in php?

Tags: php, mysql, url, while-loop, hyperlink

My code already creates a table of images of record albums covers from a mysql query. I'm trying to add a link to the images that will send the image "id" to another page. This page will be a template for all linked images. The passed id will allow me to query the table for information about that particular album.

```
 <?php
 include('conn.php');

 $loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM vinyl ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 32") or die (mysqli_error($conn));


 $column_count = 4;
 $i = 1;

 echo '<table cellpadding="2">';

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop)) 
 {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $artist = $row['artist'];
   $album = $row['album'];
   $image = $row['coverA'];
   $image_src = "uploads/".$image;
   $alt = $artist." >> ".$album;

   if ($i == 1) { echo '<tr>'; }

   ?>

    <td><a href="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" width="300px" height="300px" /></a></td>

 <?php
  $i++;

  if ($i > $column_count) { $i=1; echo '</tr>'; }
  }

  echo '</table>';

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is just the id of the row. If you want to send it as a variable, first you need the url to the page, and then mark it as a GET variable.

```
<a href="somepage.php?id=<?=$row["id"]?>">
```

---

Then on `somepage.php`:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing this part "id=<?".

Comment: @ScottC if I answered your question, please click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it.